# Integrate Ext JS 4.1 MVC application in a rewriten URL (mod_rewrite) in development and production

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

Creating a new Ext JS 4.1.1 app based on the file structure section in Sencha's [MVC Application Architecture guide](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#/guide/application_architecture) I end up with this structure:

```
/wwwroot
    /myapplication
        /app
            /controller
            /view
        app.js
    /extjs-4.1.1
```

The app.js file contains:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true
});

Ext.application({
    appFolder: '/myapplication/app',
    autoCreateViewport: true,
    name: 'MyApplication',
    controllers: [
        ...
    ]
});
```

All fine. I then include the app.js to be outputted in my **server-side** MVC application (not to be confused with the **client-side** Ext JS MVC structure). The language used and structure of the server-side application is of no importance to this question, but the result of the output is. In development, the URL of the application is:

```
http://servername/someidentifier1/someidentifier2
```

As in many applications, mod_rewrite is used to give meaning to the identifiers and map the URL to server-side code. These identifiers **do not** map to "physical" directories. The output of this URL is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>MyApplication</title>
<link href="/extjs-4.1.1/resources/css/ext-all-debug.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
<script type="text/javascript" src="/extjs-4.1.1/ext-debug.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/myapplication/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Ext JS is not at the default recommended location, being /wwwroot/myapplication/extjs-4.1.1, but instead one level up since it is shared between multiple applications. If you look back at the app.js above, you also notice the appFolder setting which needs to be set in order for this to work with the "non existing" URL.

This all works fine in development, but the next step is to generate a "build" of the code with the [Sencha SDK Tools](http://www.sencha.com/products/sdk-tools/) (question is based on version 2.0.0 Beta 3 for Windows).
This is where it goes wrong. I take these steps:

1. Command line I go into the /wwwroot/myapplication directory.
2. I execute `sencha create jsb -a http://servername/someidentifier1/someidentifier2 -p myapplication.jsb3` to generate a jsb3 file.
3. I execute `sencha build -p myapplication.jsb3 -d .`

The build fails. In this case because it tries to find the custom code for e.g. controllers in the path c:\...\myapplication\myapplication\app\controller: the current path + the appFolder setting. You would assume running it one level higher would be better, but then it cannot find the (shared) extjs-4.1.1 directory.

I would guess time will make the Ext JS MVC structure and SDK Tools more flexible and deviating slightly from the default structure is not recommended. All acceptable, but on the other hand: integrating Ext JS 4.x (Ext JS in an MVC way) with URL rewriting (mod_rewrite) must be a very common practice too?

Any suggested working set up/structure would be highly appreciated.

Goals should be:

- No manual editing of the jsb3 file.
- Keeping the extjs-4.1.1 directory at the top level to be shared among applications.
- Having no app.html file since it is never used in server-side MVC applications and would otherwise require manual updates.
- A nice extra would be to have the content of app.js inside the server-side generated HTML since it would then be able to receive dynamically generated parameters.

Comment: To the ones that are interested:
[this blog post](http://blog.lansdowntech.com/2012/02/creating-an-extjs-production-build-with-sencha-sdk-tools/) helps you get into the right direction (although not specifically linked to rewritten url's).

Comment: Did you figure out answer to your original question?

Comment: No, the closest I could get to the goals is having an absolute path in the appFolder and manually replacing it in the JSB3 file in-between `sencha create jsb` and `sencha build`. As weird as my original question may sound if you are not used to URL rewriting, I am more than convinced this must be a common (but fairly new) problem.

Comment: I do the same thing (renaming app.js back and forth during build) to create several web applications from one code base.

Answer (score 0):

Couple things.

First - you don't need to specify absolute path for ExtJs library and for your app in the loader.

```
...
appFolder: 'app' // should be enough
...
```

Second - as for differences between build and production - I ended up having two .html files - index.html and index-dev.html. These files don't get changed (once you set them up) so it's not a problem to keep them in sync.

You use index-dev.html for your development needs, debug and also for build process. Basically this file is configured for your local development environment.

index.html just uses combined and minified version of your app.js and configured for production deployment.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, but what you state is only applicable for a stand-alone Ext Js app. There is no integration with a server-side set-up (except for possible Ajax calls maybe).
But the question is about integration into a server-side project which outputs the html (and preferably the javascript). Such projects are often based on URL rewriting and this creates a problem for the default set-up you mention.

Comment: I don't understand. Are you generating your ExtJs code by some server side code?

Comment: Do you have any experience with URL rewriting? Otherwise it might be hard to explain.
The application is reached through the URL mentioned above, http://servername/someidentifier1/someidentifier2 and this returns HTML that is similar to app.html but contains other application specific tags and content (the title-tag for instance, but much more). But this is out of scope for the question. Fact is that a server-side MVC application must be able to generate the HTML (and preferable, the app.js content).

Comment: I do know what's URL rewriting is. I'm not sure how exactly you will generate app.js though... What exactly you want to change in app.js dynamically?

Comment: app.js specifically because I think that would be the easiest way to pass dynamically generated configuration options to the JS app? The only other ways I could think about are: global variables in the HTML (bad) or an Ajax call after launch (bad, slowdown). But I might be wrong about that part: maybe there are other ways. But again: this is not really the question. The set-up itself must be really common when you integrate Ext JS with a (existing) server-side application. I wonder how others solved it.

Comment: I don't think you can do this (dynamically create minified complete app.js file that is). I would go with Ajax calls.

Comment: I guess you can replace some of the elements in already generated app.js file by your server side, but this has nothing to do with generating complete app.js file - this part still should be done statically on your development machine.

Comment: I am afraid you are not able to answer the question. It is about integrating Ext JS 4.x/4.1.x into a server-side (MVC) application and the way this version of Ext JS "supports" that.
Since you have no experience with that side, I hope someone else can shed a light on how they approached this. But thanks for your efforts!

Comment: I don't think you clearly described what exactly are you trying to achieve. You had some building issue and I understood that. But as far as `integrating` - you probably need to be more specific.

Comment: As stated in the original post, the question is not about the failing build itself, but on the de facto way Ext JS 4.x gets implemented into server-side MVC projects. I tried to describe that situation staying as close to the Sencha MVC application architecture guide as possible and pointing out the issues along the way. I of course get that Ext JS 4.x works very well stand-alone, but that are only a part of the real-world applications. Let's see if anyone else can add to this...

Answer (score 0):

Using mod rewrite you can use a slightly modified .htaccess file from Symfony

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    #<IfModule mod_vhost_alias.c>
    #    RewriteBase /
    #</IfModule>

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

This file let you

- get resource from server if they are real files (css, js, images, etc.)
- convert url parts to query parameters if there aren't matches on server filesystem.

This should work on your setup, just change the app.php line to your application entrypoint

for directory setup, yours is fine, just a couple of things:

- your SDK tools are outdated, since you can download:
  http://www.sencha.com/products/sencha-cmd/download/ (v3.0.0)
- following docs at http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide/command you can get a "build" with the class you need, but in the end or you manually switch between development / production javascript file, or you switch using environments variables in your code.
- Actually I think you could use a "fake" index.html in build directory to be modified by building tool then in production code you can mimic the code generated by sencha build.

Comment: Thank you for your post but the question is related to how to set up Ext JS, in an URL-rewritten environment. The URL rewriting itself is not relevant to the question (and is server-side framework dependent, which the question is not).

Answer (score 0):

Creating a index.html file to generate the project file will be a way to go. I also found that sencha architect is very rigid and hard to use. The most annoy thing is that I can't use the external editor to edit the generated code. Everything have to be done in the designer, which is fine if the designer can provide every functionality I need. But it can't.